# Simple device (fancy) pointer implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

`device_raw_ptr` is a simple fancy pointer. It essentially wrap pointers to GPU memory. It's sole purpose is to separate out host pointers from device pointers, i.e. they should not be inter-convertible and must not be dereferenced. At the same time, they should be zero-cost (with respect to raw host pointers) and be maximally compatible with regular pointers.

**Helper class:**

```
template <class T>
struct equality_operators {
    /* 
    ** The deriving class must implement the following:
    ** friend bool operator==(const T&, const T&);
    */

    friend bool operator!=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return !static_cast<bool>(lhs == rhs); }
};

template <class T>
struct less_than_operators {
    /* 
    ** The deriving class must implement the following:
    ** friend bool operator<(const T&, const T&);
    */

    friend bool operator>(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)  { return rhs < lhs; }
    friend bool operator<=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return !static_cast<bool>(lhs > rhs); }
    friend bool operator>=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return !static_cast<bool>(lhs < rhs); }
};

template <class T>
struct relational_operators : equality_operators<T>, less_than_operators<T> { };
```

**`device_raw_ptr` implementation:**

```
template <class T>
    class device_raw_ptr : public relational_operators<T> {
        static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<T>::value, "T must satisfy StandardLayoutType");
    public:
        using element_type = std::remove_extent_t<T>;

        constexpr device_raw_ptr() noexcept = default;
        constexpr device_raw_ptr(std::nullptr_t) noexcept : ptr { nullptr } { }
        constexpr device_raw_ptr(const device_raw_ptr& other) noexcept = default;
        explicit device_raw_ptr(element_type* ptr_) noexcept : ptr{ ptr_ } { }
        device_raw_ptr(device_raw_ptr&& other) noexcept : ptr{ other.ptr } { other.reset(); }

        device_raw_ptr& operator=(const device_raw_ptr& other) noexcept { 
            swap(device_raw_ptr(other), *this); 
            return *this;
        }

        device_raw_ptr& operator=(device_raw_ptr&& other) noexcept { 
            swap(device_raw_ptr(other), *this);
            return *this;
        }

        void reset() noexcept { ptr = nullptr; }
        void reset(T* ptr_) noexcept { ptr = ptr_; }

        element_type* get() noexcept { return ptr; };
        const element_type* get() const noexcept { return ptr; }

        friend void swap(device_raw_ptr& lhs, device_raw_ptr& rhs) noexcept {
            using std::swap;
            std::swap(lhs.ptr, rhs.ptr);
        }

        explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return static_cast<bool>(ptr); }

        device_raw_ptr& operator++() noexcept {
            ++ptr;
            return *this;
        }

        device_raw_ptr operator++(int) noexcept {
            device_raw_ptr tmp(*this);
            ptr++;
            return tmp;
        }

        device_raw_ptr& operator+=(std::ptrdiff_t offset) noexcept {
            ptr += offset;
            return *this;
        }

        device_raw_ptr& operator-=(std::ptrdiff_t offset) noexcept {
            ptr -= offset;
            return *this;
        }

        friend device_raw_ptr& operator+(device_raw_ptr lhs, std::ptrdiff_t offset) noexcept {
            lhs += offset;
            return lhs;
        }

        friend device_raw_ptr& operator-(device_raw_ptr lhs, std::ptrdiff_t offset) noexcept {
            lhs -= offset;
            return lhs;
        }

        /* required by relational_operators base class */
        friend bool operator==(const device_raw_ptr& lhs, const device_raw_ptr& rhs) noexcept { return lhs.ptr == rhs.ptr; }
        friend bool operator<(const device_raw_ptr& lhs, const device_raw_ptr& rhs) noexcept { return lhs.ptr < rhs.ptr; }

    protected:
        T *ptr;
    };

    template <class T, class U, class V>
    std::basic_ostream<U, V>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<U, V>& os, const device_raw_ptr<T>& other) {
        os << other.get() << " (device)";
        return os;
    }
```

I am also looking for suggestions on how to order different things inside a class.

Might it be better to initialize with `nullptr` instead of the default constructor. This breaks compatibility but I think it might be worth considering the compiler would mostly optimize the assignment if it's immediately overwritten.

Comment: I just noticed that I am passing rvalues to `swap` which accepts non-const lvalue as arguments.  You can find it in the copy & move constructor.

Comment: If anyone did not notice, I messed up the `relational_operator` inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

1. `device_raw_ptr` is extremely cheap to copy, so remove all hints of move-semantics and use of `swap()`.
2. Now you can remove the copy-constructor and copy-assignment, as there is no need to explicitly declare them. Especially making them user-defined must be avoided to keep them trivial.
3. Kudos on trying to use the approved two-step for `swap()`. Though you get a failing grade anyway because you bungled it by using a qualified call in the second part. Hopefully, C++20 will abolish that nonsense by introducing [customization point objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495848/what-are-customization-point-objects-and-how-to-use-them).
4. Yes, you should pass your `device_raw_ptr` by value if you have the choice, as it is a tiny trivial type. Still, refrain from returning a reference to such a temporary.
5. There is no reason `operator-(device_raw_ptr, std::ptrdiff_t)` should not be `constexpr`. Aside from your implementation for some reason delegating to `operator-=`, which is not. Same for `operator+` which uses `operator+=`.
6. Is there any reason you don't support subtracting a `device_raw_ptr` from another?
7. I'm really puzzled why you make the only data-member `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Wouldn't the implicitly defined copy-assignment operator return a reference?

Comment: I have incorporated the changes you suggested. Please check [latest code](https://gist.github.com/YashasSamaga/a57fba277c310cdede32c9618b124e4b)

Answer (score 2):

**Helper classes**

There is no need to use `static_cast<bool>` for your comparisons.  The relational operators are already `bool` values.  (If they are not, that is a problem with the definition of the operator for the type `T`.)

The standard `<utility>` header provides definitions for `operator!=` (from `operator==`) and `operator>`, `operator<=`, and `operator>=` (from `operator<`).  There is no need for you to define those four operators if you have the other two (equality and less-than).

Why do you have the `relational_operators` struct at all?  It shouldn't be necessary.

**Implementation**

The default constructor for `device_raw_ptr` leaves the `ptr` member uninitialized.  Typically a class like this would initialize `ptr` to `nullptr`, and you wouldn't need the constructor that takes a `std::nullptr_t` object.

The copy assignment operator should just be `ptr = other.ptr`, since that is the only thing in your class.  The way you have it is nonstandard behavior.  You construct a temporary, then pass it as a non-const reference to `swap`.  This is not supported as part of the language, although some compilers (MSVC) support it as an extension. You're constructing a temporary, doing a swap, then destroying the temporary (a noop in this case).  Similarly, the move assignment operator can be simplified to not use the temporary (`ptr = other.ptr; other.reset();`, or use three statements with an assignment to a local to avoid problems if you move assign an object to itself).

`operator bool` does not need a `static_cast`.  Perhaps an explicit `ptr != nullptr` check, although a pointer will implicitly convert to a `bool`.

Comment: I thought using `std::rel_ops` is generally frowned upon. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225375/idiomatic-use-of-stdrel-ops suggests using `boost:operators`. I wrote my own version instead.

Comment: The default constructor leaves `ptr` unitialized because that's how raw pointers behave (initialized with garbage?). But I am considering the option of initializing it to `nullptr`. The `std::nullptr_t` is a consequence of the aforementioned statement. I intended to have a `constexpr` constructor which sets `ptr` to `nullptr`.

Comment: For the abuse of swap, I made started (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217019/simple-device-fancy-pointer-implementation/217024#comment419761_217019) using temporaries right after I posted the question. It was an attempt to reuse the constructors to perform move/copy but I think it was overkill for such a simple class.

Comment: @Yashas `std::rel_ops` is there to avoid having duplicate definitions of those relational operators.  If a class does not want some of them (as mentioned in your linked question), then it should define _all_ of them, and `= delete` the ones it doesn't want to support.  But its up to you to decide how to implement them.

Comment: @Yashas leaving raw pointer uninitialized is, generally, a bad idea.  The cost of assigning a `nullptr` someplace where it isn't strictly necessary is outweighed by the predictability and consistent (mis)behavior the NULL value will give you.